# Exponential/Logarithmic Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Being stated as the answer to a certain problem in a physics textbook the following inequality is implied:

$$
\ln{T} ≤ \mu\theta + C
\implies T ≤ T_{0}e^{\mu\theta}
$$

It is also stated that as an initial condition $T=T_{0}$ when $\theta=0$.

Where does the $T_{0}$ come from in the inequality above? Why is it needed?

---

From *Classical Mechanics* by *D. Morin* Chapter I: Statics pI-5

Comment: $T_0 = e^C {}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\exp$ in an increasing function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, the inequality is conserved by composing by $\exp$:

$$\exp(\ln T)\leqslant \exp(\mu\theta+C)=\exp(C)\exp(\mu\theta)$$

Conclude by defining $T_0:=\exp C$.